# Cropping Image without creating new file

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, crop

I have this piece of code that gets image from gallery, then passes it to intent to get cropped. Everything works fine but this either creates new cropped image in gallery or replaces the old image with cropped one but what I want to do is to keep new cropped image in my programs temporary memory until it is again changed by user.

Here is my code:

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                intent.setData(selectedImage);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", width);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", height);
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", width);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", height);
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
                intent.putExtra("output", selectedImage); // with this enabled it replaces the original image and without it creates new one in gallery.
                startActivityForResult(intent, 23);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a temporary file that you will delete afterwards :

```
    (...)
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("crop", "png", Environment
                                            .getExternalStorageDirectory());
    Uri tempUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
    intent.putExtra("output", tempUri);
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", "PNG");
    (...)

    // then, when the intent returns

    // read cropped image from tempUri
    (...)
    // finally delete the temp file
    tempFile.delete();
```